# Resources on sibling sub module, Gradle project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to migrate my company's project from Maven to Gradle, so far I've been able to convert all POMs to the corresponding build.gradle files, but I ran across an issue in a sub module when building.

```
- Core-UI
---- Utils
---- FieldPanels
```

The sub module FieldPanel uses colors and other resources defined in Utils. I tried adding the Utils project as a dependency, but it did not work, what am I missing?

```
/home/development/AndroidStudioProjects/com.project/core-ui/common.android.fieldpanels/build/bundles/debug/res/layout/base_summary_step_layout.xml:2: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/wizard_summary_bg').
```

**Utils gradle.build**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
            res {
                srcDirs = [
                        'res'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '17.0'

    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.company.ipos.android', name: 'commons.pos.micropos.api', version: '0.0.35-SNAPSHOT'
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }

        url repoUrl
    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }

        url libsReleasesUrl
    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }

        url libsSnapshotsUrl
    }
}
```

**fieldPanels gradle.build**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

repositories {
    maven {
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }

        url repoUrl
    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }

        url libsReleasesUrl
    }
    maven {
        credentials {
            username mavenUser
            password mavenPassword
        }

        url libsSnapshotsUrl
    }
}

android {
    dependencies {
        compile group: 'com.company.ipos.android', name: 'commons.pos.micropos.api', version: '0.0.35-SNAPSHOT'
        //compile group: 'com.company.ipos.android', name: 'common.android.utils', version: '0.0.35-SNAPSHOT'
        compile project(":common.android.utils")
        compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.6.5'
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest {
                srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            }
            res {
                srcDirs = [
                        'res',
                ]
            }
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '17.0'
}
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle files ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have done that sooner.

Comment: That seems fine. Have you included the two projects in the setting.gradle file?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem: library projects apparently do not resolve references to other library projects...

Answer (score 2):

Can you include your settings.gradle. I'm wondering if you have an incorrect path in your compile dependency.

Here is how you have declared the dependency from fieldPanels to utils

```
compile project(":common.android.utils")
```

What this means is that the utils library module must be known to gradle ":common.android.utils". Perhaps it should be this instead?

```
compile project(":Core-UI:Utils")
```

Comment: I have setup the library projects and that works, but the problem is specific with resources that are shared among library projects. Imagine you have 2 library projects LA and LB and LB depends on LA. If I reference a resource in LB that is from LA, compilation will fail, saying it can not find the R.id.whatever. (So referencing normal Java code works just fine...)

Comment: @jtietema not to say what you want to do can't be done.  Have you explored creating an explicit task dependency where the compile tasks in LA depend on the resource generation phase of LB, and vice versa?  The `R` class is generated before your source is compiled so I don't see why something like that would not work.

Comment: @DavidCowden all things Java work fine. My problem is specific with resource id's. It seems I can only reference library resource ids from an app project and not from other library projects. I am suspecting this has something to do with resource ids not being constant, but change after compilation.

Comment: @jtietema Can you please share the package for the fieldPanels project as well as the resource reference you are using to refer to the R.id.whatever?

Answer (score 1):

Taking your example of "2 library projects LA and LB and LB depends on LA" here are a couple of working examples.

Let's say LA has the following strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="la_resource">la resource</string>
</resources>
```

Let's say LB has the following strings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="lb_resource">lb resource</string>
</resources>
```

Let's say we want to define a custom view named TestView in LB. TestView will reference la_resource from LA and lb_resource from LB. Here is the source for TestView

```
package com.example.myapplication3.lb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestView extends TextView {
    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setText(context.getString(R.string.la_resource) + " " + context.getString(R.string.lb_resource));
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setText(context.getString(R.string.la_resource) + " " + context.getString(R.string.lb_resource));
    }

    public TestView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setText(context.getString(R.string.la_resource) + " " + context.getString(R.string.lb_resource));
    }
}
```

Let's say we want to define another custom view named TestView2 in LB. TestView2 will inflate an XML layout. The XML layout will reference la_resource from LA and lb_resource from LB. Here is the source for TestView2

```
package com.example.myapplication3.lb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class TestView2 extends FrameLayout {
    public TestView2(Context context) {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_view_2, this);
    }

    public TestView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_view_2, this);
    }

    public TestView2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_view_2, this);
    }
}
```

And here is the source for test_view_2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/la_resource"
        android:padding="4dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lb_resource" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're running into this problem building in the Android Studio/IDEA, don't forget to check the `library` checkbox on your library modules in the project settings.

Also, try to use a different version of android plugin, 0.8+, for example.
And one more thought: there was and maybe still are different problems with android plugin and 7 java, if you use it, try to use 6.